# Issues with file upload fields

Tags: files

I'm working on a site where someone did a lot of security updates. After reviewing the site, we found a bug. When you try creating a node with a file upload, when you click the save button, instead of saving it actually downloads the file to your computer. I'm not really sure where to start looking for this issue.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: does it actually upload properly prior to the save if you 'choose' and then 'upload'?

Comment: yes it does, thats what makes it weirder. It clearly has the correct permissions etc to upload properly

Comment: that is weird - I would suggest disabling modules one by one to see if it's actually a module causing the problem - disable (not uninstall) everything in sequence not directly required for that one page to function as intended (on a dev copy of course)

Comment: Ok found out one more thing: If after I upload i uncheck 'Include File in Display', the it saves ok. I searched for that text and found that its set by the core file module.... Does this help?

Comment: if you don't need that functionality, you can turn it off in the field settings - temporary, but might be a viable option for now. Does the node save after the file downloads, or does the page change at all?

Comment: Well, I found that I can't really turn it off. I found that there is a view of these nodes which lists the node titles linking to the node content. When its checked off, it automatially downloads the file, which is what we want. When its not checked off, it brings the user to the node page.

Comment: you should be able to alter the behaviour of the view by overriding the output of the field, but the exact method depends entirely on the setup of the view and fields involved

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I found this stuck in the node template:

```
<?php if (!empty($node->field_white_paper_file['und'][0])){
  drupal_goto(file_create_url($node->field_white_paper_file['und'][0]['uri']));
 }?>
```